# Is it bad for accessibility to repeat the main navigation in markup?

Tags: css, navigation, accessibility, display

Often when creating a mobile version of the navigation, the most straightforward way for it to work with the design is to repeat the main navigation markup and hide one or the other with `display:none` in CSS depending on the screen resolution.

Is this bad for accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently inaccessible with this approach.
Using `display:none` will hide content from all users and will not be read aloud by screen readers.

> `visibility: hidden; and/or display:none;`
>
> These styles will hide text from all users. The text is removed from the visual flow of the page and is ignored by screen readers. **Do not use this CSS if you want the content to be read by a screen reader. But DO use it for content you don't want read by screen readers**.
>
> https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about the case when someone has CSS disabled, which I guess could be something that some users do for accessibility reasons - you'd then get the navigation twice.

Comment: Back when Section 508 was the main accessibility standard (before WGAG was released), there were some checkpoints that required developers to disable CSS to ensure proper reading order, alt text, and contrast requirements. To the best of my knowledge, it's not very common for actual screen-reader users to disable CSS. In some ways, the screen-reader by it's very nature bypasses many of the presentational aspects of CSS (e.g. colors), but `display:none` is a sledgehammer, and all major screen-readers will hide this content.

Comment: If you'd like to make double sure that screen-reader users won't have to endure the navigation twice, then why not implement some skip links? It will make your site more accessible, and your users may appreciate it: 


https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/